# Recommandation on localization String in php

Tags: php, localization

I wrote a simple php localization method:

```
function localizationString($key, $local){      

        if (!isset($local)){
            $local =  substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        }  

        $arr = array("en" => array("aString" => "aString in English"),
                     "ja" => array("aString" => "aString in Japanese") );

        $result  = $arr[$local];   

    return $result[$key];                        
}
```

Every string which append to localization, I will use the localizationString call, like this:

```
echo ("Non-localization String with a localization String ".localizationString("aString", NULL));
```

Is there any recommandation for this method? 
Will there a problem if the array become very big? Is there a better way to make a better performance?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gettext](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/) for localization needs. You can use it like `echo _("Hello World!");` and it will be translated to the language of choice.